# Dojo : Array is defined at top of file but is undefined

Tags: arrays, dojo, global-variables

I have the prerequisite setup...

```
define([ "dojo/_base/array", array ...
```

I create my array "`concats`" in the "`return declare([], { concats: [], ...`" area. There is a method/function called `_createForm: function (fields) { ...}`

Inside of this function I have : `this.concats = [];`

Inside of `_createForm` is a call to another method/function called : `_createFormElement` and inside of there whenever I try to PUSH to `this.concats` I get

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

I've tried every conceivable method to add items to this array but nothing I do, short of including `this.concats = []` in the `_createFormElement` function will let me. AND if I include `this.concats = []` in the `_createFormElement` function then it erases the array...

So sure, it holds ONE object, but I need it to collect objects for each Form Field in a global-ish array.

I'm so confused.

Comment: could post a portion of your code and how do you instanttiate and use it :

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I just have to reference the "global" (but not really global) array variable like so in my `_createFormElement` function/method...

```
var myVariable = this.concats;
```

Then in that function I can push like so...

```
myVariable.push(itemToPush);
```